# GET http://localhost:3000/registro 404 (Not Found) can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a post request in frontend to make a user register, but I'm having an error "404 not found"

file **server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/conn');

const app = express();

//conectando o banco de dados
connectDB();

//iniciando o middleware
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API rodando'));

//Definindo rotas
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/users'));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server iniciado na porta ${PORT}`))
```

---

file **Registro.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../auth/Registro.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


const Registro = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
        nome:'', 
        email:'', 
        senha: '',
        senha2: ''  
    });

    const { nome, email, senha, senha2 } = formData;
    const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = async e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(senha !== senha2){
        console.log('As senhas devem ser iguais');
      } else {
        const newUser = {
          nome,
          email,
          senha,
          senha2
        }

        try {
          const config = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          }

          const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);

          const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

          console.log(res.data);

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.response.data);
          
        }
      }
    }
  return (
    <div className='section_registro'>
    <p> Página de registro! </p>

      <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <label> Insira seu nome completo </label>
          <input 
          type="text" 
          name="nome"
          value={nome}
          placeholder='nome'
          required
          onChange={e => onChange(e)} />

          <label> Insira seu email </label>
          <input 
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          placeholder='email'
          required
          onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
        
          <label> Insira sua senha </label>
          <input 
          type="password" 
          name="senha"
          value={senha}
          placeholder='senha'
          required
          onChange={e => onChange(e)} />

          <label> Confira sua senha </label>
          <input 
          type="password" 
          name="senha2"
          value={senha2}
          placeholder='senha'
          required
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
           />

           <input type='submit' value='Registro' className='btn btn-primário'/>
        
        </form>

        <p> Já tem uma conta? </p> <Link to="/login"> Login </Link> 
          
    </div>
  )
}

export default Registro
```

file **users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route POST api/users
//@desc Registro de user 
//@acess Public
router.post('/', [
    check('nome', 'Nome é obrigatório').notEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Insira um email válido').isEmail(),
    check('senha', "Senha é obrigatória").notEmpty(),

], async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { nome, email, senha, tipo } = req.body;

    try {

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (user){
            res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Esse user já existe' }] });
        }

        user = new User({
            nome,
            email,
            senha,
            tipo
        });

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

        user.senha = await bcrypt.hash(senha, salt);

        await user.save();

        const payload = {
            user:{
                id:user.id
            }
        }

        jwt.sign(
            payload, 
            config.get('jwtSecret'), 
            { expiresIn: 36000 }, (err, token) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });        
            });
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');     
    }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

idk why the browser is showing this error. It's seems like my frontend is not "finding" my backend.
error: [GET http://localhost:3000/registro 404 (Not Found)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61EZ.png)

I tried change the folder of backend and the path in server.js, but it didn't work. after that, I'm having the error that I can't get the register router, but I had the error POST http://localhost:5000/api/users 404 (Not Found)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to have any route defined for `registro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined any route for registro.
If you want to access it without route you need to make the folder, in which registro.jsx exists, public

You can do it using
app.use(express.static(folder-name));

Comment: I already changed that, but now it's showing "POST http://localhost:3000/api/users 404 (Not Found)". I'm running the backend server in another port (port 5000) and the frontend in the port 3000. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understood what was happening. I didn't put the proxy on the client side. Now it's running as well. Thanks for help everyone